# Azure Synapse serverless delete files created by a CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE AS SELECT statement

Tags: azure, t-sql, azure-storage, azure-synapse

I'm using Synapse Serverless which does not support materialized views, but some use cases need them for performance reasons. As a workaround I was going to use CETAS statements to persist files and schedule regular updates for them. However, when I try to drop and recreate a CETAS table I get message:

```
Cannot create external table. External table location already exists. Location provided: [location]
```

Once the files are created by the CETAS statement it looks like I can't overwrite them with another CETAS statement and I haven't found any other options for modifying files within synapse. I know I can create a larger workflow to delete from storage before rerunning CETAS, but was hoping there was some way to keep things contained to Synapse.

Is there some way to delete/overwrite/modify the files created by a CETAS statement from within Synapse?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you've found, dropping the table doesn't delete the files.  This is outlined in the documentation (see **Remarks** section) ...

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/drop-external-table-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#remarks

This may not suit your requirements but to overcome that, you can drop the table and recreate it with a **timestamp**.  The external table name stays as is, it's just the file that will contain the timestamp so as to differentiate it from previous creations.

[image: External Table]

An example is shown below, naturally, it's missing some context but you should get the general idea ...

```
DECLARE @CurrentTimeStamp varchar(100) = (SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(CONVERT(varchar, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 126), '-', ''), 'T', '_'), ':', ''))

BEGIN TRY
    SET @Sql = '
        IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.external_tables WHERE name = ''' + @TableName + ''' AND schema_id = ' + CAST(@SchemaIdReporting as varchar(10)) + ')
        BEGIN
            DROP EXTERNAL TABLE [reporting].[' + @TableName + ']
        END         

        CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE [reporting].[' + @TableName + ']
        WITH (
            LOCATION = ''reporting/' + @TableName + '/' + @CurrentTimeStamp + ''',
            DATA_SOURCE = [Analytics],
            FILE_FORMAT = [Parquet]
        ) AS
        ' + @Sql
    
    EXEC (@Sql)
END TRY

BEGIN CATCH
    SET @ErrorSection = 'Part 1: SQL statement construction.'
    SELECT @ErrorMessage = @ErrorSection + ', ' + ERROR_MESSAGE(), @ErrorSeverity = ERROR_SEVERITY(), @ErrorState = ERROR_STATE()

    PRINT @Sql

    RAISERROR (@ErrorMessage, @ErrorSeverity, @ErrorState)
END CATCH
```

... further to that, modifying (update/insert/delete) the data in an external table is not currently supported and is a limitation.  That can be found here ...

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-external-table-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15&tabs=dedicated#limitations-and-restrictions

The only consideration is a clean up of the old files.  I'm yet to do that but like the concept of having a snapshot of all the old data.  I haven't needed to go back and access any of it yet but it's there if I need to.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I think this will work for my use case. FYI you can set [lifecycle rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/lifecycle-management-policy-configure?tabs=azure-portal) for blob storage to handle clean up of old files automatically. Just make sure you regularly update the CETAS tables so the lifecycle rules don't delete the active files

Comment: @hamdog, thanks for the heads up.  I've been using Blob for years but haven't looked for eons on what other features have dropped.  I see it came in in 2019, I really need to do some more reading.  :-)

Comment: so, deletion of data is not possible through a t-sql query, while the same was created by a t-sql query?

Comment: @KapilShukla correct