# Merge parquet files into external tables synapse

Tags: database, azure, t-sql, extract, azure-synapse

I extract data daily from a data source and store it in Parquet, then I created an external table in synapse. I want to constantly update the external table with data that is been extracted daily. I created a notebook to create a temp table insert the new data and merge to old data but its not working.

```
CREATE TABLE #TempTable
(
    DATE DATE,
    SMD INT,
    ERK VARCHAR(50), 
    LK DATETIME,
    LDATE DATE,
    LG DATETIME,
    K DATETIME,
    G DATETIME,
    IZAR INT,
    BSL INT,
    PERS INT,
    WORK_TIME_HOURS DECIMAL(10, 2)
);

BULK INSERT #TempTable
FROM 'frr/ff_test/*.parquet'
WITH (
    DATA_SOURCE = 'PersData',
    FILE_FORMAT = 'ParquetFF'
);

MERGE INTO [Gf].[Gon_test] AS target
USING TempTable AS source
ON target.smand = source.smand 
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET
        target.DATE = source.DATE,
        target.LK = source.LK,
        target.LD = source.LD,
        target.LG = source.LG,
        target.K = source.K,
        target.G = source.G,
        target.IZAR = source.IZAR,
        target.BSL = source.SBSL,
        target.PERS = source.SPERS,
        target.WORK_TIME_HOURS = source.WORK_TIME_HOURS
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT (
        DATE, 
        SMAND,
        ERK,
        LK,
        LD,
        LG,
        KN,
        G,
        IZR,
        BSL,
        PERS,
        WORK_TIME
    )
    VALUES (
        source.DATE, 
        source.AND,
        source.ERK,
        source.LK,
        source.LD,
        source.LG,
        source.K,
        source.G,
        source.IZAR,
        source.BSL,
        source.PERS,
        source.WORK_TIME
    );

   DROP TABLE #TempTable;
```

Answer (score 1):

- It is not possible to **update/insert/merge** data in external tables. External tables point to the data that are stored in ADLS or blob storage.
- Data are not stored physically in azure synapse analytics. Any changes in the blob storage will automatically get reflected in external tables also.
- If you want to replace the old records with new records, you can write queries or views on top of the external table to take only the latest records.
- Refer the similar [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76981888/19986107) in stackoverflow, which discusses the same approach.